# Is there a way to increase the quota?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is there a way (paid or unpaid) to increase the queries per minute per user of 600 times/min when using Google calendar API?

Since there are many event updates with reflecting in real time, the allocation will be insufficient.

Only values ​​from 0 to 600 could be changed on the form.
When I clicked on the "apply for higher quota" link next to the form, I just went to the quota list screen and didn't know how to apply.

[image: Quota increase form and 'apply for higher quota' link]

Answer (score -1):

You need a billing account, which I assume you have. Then:

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=calendar-json.googleapis.com
2. From the list of quotas select the one with the "Limit name"="Queries per minute per user" by clicking on the ""ALL QUOTAS" link in the "Details" field.
3. Select the quota now by checking the checkbox.
4. Click on the "EDIT QUOTAS" button at the top of the pane.
5. In the "New limit*" field write your desired new limit.
6. Click on "SUBMIT REQUEST" button.

That's it. If you have a billing account, it should work.

---

From the docs linked here: [Manage Quotas](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/quota) you can see that a billing account is required.
[image: docs how to]

---

After that, you follow the steps listed above, and you will see a field  where Google asks you to explain the reasons for your request (See image below), and will consider if approving it or not. Continue filling in the information until you get to the "SUBMIT REQUEST" button.[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!
I have another question. 
I will try to request more than 600 as new limit. 
If my request is approved, is it goig to start billing?

Comment: It should yes. Your service provider will bill you according to the quota you spend, not your limits though.